# Disable error message: AccessDeniedException: Access is denied

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I use this custom error handler:

```
@Component
public class OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException ex) throws IOException {

        ErrorDetail errorDetail = ErrorDetail.AUTHENTICATION_ERROR;

        ErrorResponse errorEntry = new ErrorResponse();
        errorEntry.setTitle(errorDetail.getTitle());
        errorEntry.setCode(errorDetail.getErrorCode());
        HttpStatus httpStatus = ErrorDetail.getHttpStatusBasedOnErrorCode(errorDetail.getErrorCode());
        errorEntry.setStatus(httpStatus.value());
        errorEntry.setDetail(ex.getMessage());
        Map<String, String> extra = new HashMap<String, String>();
        extra.put("detail", ex.getMessage());
        errorEntry.setExtra(extra);

        ErrorResponseDTO errorResponse = new ErrorResponseDTO();
        errorResponse.setErrors(Arrays.asList(errorEntry));

        response.setStatus(errorDetail.getHttpStatus().value());
        String json = new ObjectMapper().setDefaultPropertyInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL).writeValueAsString(errorResponse);
        response.getWriter().write(json);
        response.flushBuffer();
    }
}
```

I get this error response as it should be:

```
{"errors":[{"status":404,"code":"1000","title":"Authentication error","detail":"Full authentication is required to access this resource","extra":{"detail":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}}]}
```

But I get into server log this error:

```
21:34:30.498 [http-nio-8090-exec-7] DEBUG AffirmativeBased[decide:66] - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@33252ffb, returned: -1
21:34:30.498 [http-nio-8090-exec-7] DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter[handleSpringSecurityException:180] - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
        at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
```

Do you know how I can suppress or disable this error every time when I get AuthenticationException?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a `DEBUG` level log for development purposes which is okay. On the production level, the log level should not be lower than the `WARN` level so these exceptions will not be logged and it is not a concern.

If you insist to modify the behavior anyway, Spring allows setting a log level right on the class or disable it at all using `OFF`. I find turning it off as discouraged since you might miss more severe logs as such the exception can be logged also on the different levels.

Open `application.properties` and write one of:

- Disable all logs: `org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException=OFF`
- At least `ERROR` level: `org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException=ERROR`
- At least `WARN` level: `org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException=WARN`